# How to disable argparse's wrapping an argument into a list

Tags: python, argparse

I have a parser like this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--template', metavar='FILE', nargs=1, required=True)
```

and pass the arguments like this

```
myprog --template template.txt
```

But when I later check the `args` obtained from `args = parser.parse_args()` I will get

```
['template.txt']
```

Can I get the plain `'template.txt'` instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `nargs` if you don't want it to be a list:

```
parser.add_argument('--template', metavar='FILE', required=True)
```

From the [`nargs` option documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> Note that `nargs=1` produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

and

> If the nargs keyword argument is not provided, the number of arguments consumed is determined by the action. Generally this means a single command-line argument will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced.